# How to estimate memory requirement for freeRTOS

Tags: memory-management, freertos

[image]
[image]

https://www.freertos.org/FAQMem.html#RAMUse

I understand that the higher number of priorities, the more memory is required. But without compiling the code, is there a way to estimate the RAM/ ROM usage if I have more priorities? e.g. 16?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of priorities makes a little, but largely insignificant difference to the memory consumption of the kernel - I think limited to one additional `List_t` structure per priority level, see https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS-Kernel/blob/V10.3.1-kernel-only/tasks.c#L343